# Is it possible to access Firebase realtime database when the device is offline?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-connection

I'm developing a native Android application to show rock climbing topos, I receive all the routes and degrees from Firebase's real-time database. However, I thought it would be stupid to require internet all the time since in some places people won't have internet access when climbing.

Now, I'm planning to put a download option so people can store that Firebase data in their devices so they can access them offline.

Is this possible?

I found this:

```
DatabaseReference gradesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("grades");
gradesRef.orderByValue().limitToLast(4).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
      System.out.println("The " + snapshot.getKey() + " climbing grade is " + snapshot.getValue());
    }
});
```

to **Querying Data Offline** but I'm not sure it's the same thing I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, using this line of code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

This means that you'll have a copy of your data locally and you'll be able to query it and also every change you'll make while you are offiline, will be visible in the database once you are back online.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So once they use the app online, they won't need internet access again right? (unless they want to receive updates)

Comment: When the users are offline, they don't need internet access. If they want to receive an update or they want to update treir database according with the changes made while they were offline, they will need to get internet access. This the one of the benefits of Firebase.